# Velocity limit of UMTS and (or) CDMA2000

Tags: rf, cellphone

If the client is moving relative to the base station, the Doppler shift would compress or extend the packet. If the effect is strong enough, the PN generator in the receiver will eventually get out of sync with the signal and the packet won't be received completely.

What relative speed can UMTS and (or) CMDA2000 tolerate?

Or is this somehow compensated for?

Comment: It looks like cellphones work in airplanes, so it can work there. Are you looking for actual physical limits or guarantees made by some standards?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see..

If your going at the speed of sound the radio frequency change is -0.000114412% ([Source](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/phys/default/doppler))...

You would need to be going extremely fast for this to become a factor.

Comment: Ok, so we have error of 1×10¯⁶. Now what is the number of cycles of the PN generator per packet? Is it really less than 10⁶? By how much?

Comment: @JanHudec that depends on the packet size.

Answer (score 0):

These standards do allow for some frequency error due to doppler shift.

The theory behind this is quite complex, I found [this thesis](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099.1/9873/Sensitivity%20of%20mobile%20devices%20to%20Doppler%20shifts%20and%20poor%20s%E2%80%A6.pdf) which describes some of the limitations.

Usually these standards do allow usage in cars and trains (obviously since we use that daily) up to certain speeds. Some high speed trains might be on the edge of what is reasonably possible.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum speed for GSM is 250km/h (GSM900) or 130 km/h (GSM1800). And the limitation is mainly for handing over a phone from one cell tower to another.

For UMTS the speed is 500km/h.

CDMA2000 I have no idea.

Comment: A nice article that address future challenges with moving in high speed and mobile calls https://the8layers.com/2017/02/07/gsm-r-lte-r-and-hyperloop-at-1200-kph/